# Flutter firebase messaging GetInitialMessage blocking app from starting

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am creating a streaming app that include some kind of notifications using fcm.
i want to collect the initial fcm message if the app is killed, but this is blocking my app from starting.
this is called in the MyApp widget, in the iniState.
this code include my main function and my application
my code:

```
Future<void> setup() async {
  await FlutterNotificationChannel.registerNotificationChannel(
    description: 'General Notification Channel',
    id: 'message',
    importance: NotificationImportance.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
    name: 'general',
    allowBubbles: true,
    enableVibration: true,
    enableSound: true,
    showBadge: true,
  );
  await FlutterNotificationChannel.registerNotificationChannel(
    description: 'Promotional Messages from the app developer',
    id: 'link',
    importance: NotificationImportance.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
    name: 'promotional messages',
    allowBubbles: true,
    enableVibration: true,
    enableSound: true,
    showBadge: true,
  );
  await FlutterNotificationChannel.registerNotificationChannel(
    description: 'Live Events notifications',
    id: 'live',
    importance: NotificationImportance.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
    name: 'Live Events',
    allowBubbles: true,
    enableVibration: true,
    enableSound: true,
    showBadge: true,
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await Settings.init();
  if (Settings.getValue<bool>("push", true)) {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('global');
  } else {}
}

Future<void> main() async {
  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
    backgroundMessageport.sendPort,
    backgroundMessageIsolateName,
  );
  backgroundMessageport.listen(backgroundMessagePortHandler);
  setup();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);
  if (await SimpleConnectionChecker.isConnectedToInternet()) {
    isConnected = true;
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('myurl'));
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        _data = json.decode(response.body);
        channel = response.body.jsonList((e) => Channel.fromJson(e));
        break;
      default:
        {
          showToast('error: ${response.body.toString()}');
        }
    }
  } else {
    isConnected = false;
  }
  runApp(Provider.value(
    value: adState,
    builder: (context, child) => MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
      SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [
        SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
      ],
    );
    getInitialFCMNotification();
  }

  Future<void> getInitialFCMNotification() async {
    RemoteMessage? message =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (message != null) {
      showToast('got notification!');
    }
  }
}
```

runing this code will keep my app stuck, ui is not rendered.

Comment: Do you know exactly which part of the code is the problem? If not, try commenting out code until it starts working again. That will help you narrow down the cause of the issue

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code, you have a `context` error. trying to access `context` when it's not yet available.